# Magento looks in base folder and not in Theme Folder

Tags: magento, layout, reference, themes

i've try to do this in so many ways and keep getting the same results, this is what i'm doing:

under

```
app/design/frontend/default/new-theme/layout/
```

i have created a local.xml to replace some code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <catalog_product_view translate="label">
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/new-view.phtml">
                <block type="catalog/product_view_media" name="product.info.media" as="media" template="catalog/product/view/new-media.phtml"/>    

                <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.addto" as="addto" template="catalog/product/view/addto.phtml"/>
                <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.addtocart" as="addtocart" template="catalog/product/view/new-addtocart.phtml"/>

            </block>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

The problem is when i go to the product page to check Template Path Hints is telling me that Magento is looking for the template in

```
frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/new-view.phtml
```

In the backend i have setup templates, css and translations to come from new-theme folder.

Can anyone tell me where am i doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your local.xml may not be read.

Try adding your layout to page.xml where needed.

Or flush cache.

Use the following to get a dump of any page's built xml to further troubleshoot:

```
        $oRequest  = Mage::app()->getRequest();
        $info = sprintf(
            "\nRequest: %s\nFull Action Name: %s_%s_%s\nHandles:\n\t%s\nUpdate XML:\n%s",
            $oRequest->getRouteName(),
            $oRequest->getRequestedRouteName(),      //full action name 1/3
            $oRequest->getRequestedControllerName(), //full action name 2/3
            $oRequest->getRequestedActionName(),     //full action name 3/3
            implode( "\n\t", Mage::app()->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles() ),
            Mage::app()->getLayout()->getUpdate()->asString()
        );
        // Force logging to var/log/layout.log
        Mage::log($info, Zend_Log::INFO, 'layout.log', true);
```

> @per Alan Storm

Comment: Turns out the server i'm working with was not deploying changes as i upload to the repository.

The original code was fine